# Изменение любого color в более серый, как в пиксельных раскрасках

Tags: c#, unity3d, color

При создании пиксельной раскраски образовалась такая проблема. При получении пикселя из картинки GetPixel, мне нужно полученный оттуда цвет (Color32) преобразовать в более серый, как в обычных пиксельных раскрасках, когда тебе дают холст с пикселями для рисования. Была идея менять параметры цвета по HSV, но не допёр как мне из Color32 менять параметры по HSV.

Answer (score 1):

У Color есть два статических метода для конвертации
[`Color.HSVToRGB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.HSVToRGB.html) и [`Color.RGBToHSV`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.RGBToHSV.html)

Answer (score 0):

ну, я сделал немного по другому. я короче просто из полученного из пикселя цвета взял у него R и подставил этот R Под G, B. И у меня получился более менее различные серые цвета

Comment: Это не будет работать случае, если R-составляющая будет равна 0.

Comment: ну, там уже можно если к примеры R будет меньше или равна к примеру 15, тогда уже все параметры по G, если и тот меньше 15, то уже тогда по B

Answer (score -1):

Смотри, согласно спецификации юнити Color32 это просто RGBA.
Каждый канал имеет значение от 0 до 255.

Для изменения оттенка к более светлому или более темному нужно в каждом из каналов RGB добавить/убавить некую статическую цифру.

Чем ближе все цифры этого канала к нулю - тем ближе будет цвет к черному. Чем ближе все цифры к 255 - тем ближе к белому.

Чем более усредненные эти цифры - тем более серым получится цвет. Фактически, ты можешь опытным путем подобрать добавление процента серости если напишешь простой код который будет изменять цифры на некий процент к среднему значению из этих трех значений.

Если ты хочешь полную конвертацию в серый, можешь просто взять все 3 значения, найти среднее целое число и просто во все RGB записать это число. Получится идеальный серый цвет.

Comment: Плохой ответ. Прямая серого, о которой вы говорите, называется grey scale и она имеет очень косвенное отношение к конвертации цвета в серый оттенок. Напрямую менять значений на какой-то "процент" относительно изначального цвета не получится - вы получите более темный, но все же изначальный оттенок, но никак не серый тон. Брать среднее значение среди всех каналов можно, но тогда некоторые **разные** цвета будут преобразованы в одинаковый grayscale эквивалент, что не совсем верно.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а теперь перечитай предпоследний абзац. В задании написано **"преобразовать в более серый"**. Вот предпоследний абзац вот конкретно **это** и описывает. То есть **добавить серости в этот цвет**. А не перевод в серый цвет в принципе. :) а то что последний абзац не лучший выход - это да. Но это тоже выход и всего лишь один из путей перевода в полностью серый цвет.

Comment: 1. Это не мой вопрос. 2. Перечитай еще раз мой комментарий, rgb -> grayscale - простейшее преобразование, которое давно придумали и 10 раз расписали везде, где только можно. Сидеть и тыкать пальцем в небо и говорить "ну давайте возьмем среднее" - это плохой ответ, о чем я и написал.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker: по поводу `...разные цвета будут преобразованы в одинаковый...`. Я очень удивлюсь, если Вы представите такой алгоритм, который каждый из 256^3 возможных RGB цветов преобразовывает в разные значения однобайтовых серых)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, все просто - посмотрите формулу коквертации rgb -> luminance. Разумеется разные цвета могут дать одинаковый результат, но данная формула дает более достоверный результат при не самых больших затратах.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker: нет, это прекрасно ясно. Формула складывается из восприятия нашим глазом разных цветов, так что результат, понятное дело, будет, как Вы выразились, более достоверным. Просто Вы выразили недовольство именно по поводу того, что разные цвета дают один и тот же результирующий оттенок серого. Я высказался насчёт того, что 256^3 значений нельзя без повторений ужать в 256 возможных ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, справедливое замечание, я имел в виду ошибку среднего значении при двух абсолютно разных цветах, к примеру. Формула в моем комментарии выше не имеет такой проблемы, но цвета, разумеется, будут повторятся.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker: ну вот, славно, разъяснилось)